# Code signing identities not found for watchos 2.0

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode7, ios9, watchos-2

Trying to build the Lister for watchOS, iOS and OSX from 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Objective_C_ListerKit__WatchOS__AAPLConnectivityListsController_m.html

using Xcode 7.0 beta,

but Xcode 7.0 keep complaining 
Code Sign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'Watch OS 2.0'

I don't understand why is this happening, 
do I have to create a new certificate for the apple watchos 2.0 manually ?

Comment: Are you running in simulator or device? If device then you must have signing identity or developer program, but if you run in simulator it must be correct.

Comment: @Seyyed i am running on actual watch. just cannot figure out what is wrong with the code signing.

Comment: Are you a member of the paid Apple Developer Program or iOS Developer Program? If so, sign in with that Apple ID used for it to Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion Seyyed, I deleted active provisioning profiles, and then create a new wildcard provisioning profile, and install it on dev machine, and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted active provisioning profiles, and then created a new wildcard provisioning profile, and installed it on dev machine, and everything works now.

What happened was the project was first opened by Xcode 6.3, which generates all the provisioning profiles for all targets, **except** watchOS, because it does not recognize watchOS, so the provisioning profile for the app.watchos was missing.